# How can I transform my dataframe from wide to long format with variables recorded at different times?

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot-table, tidyr

I am working on database that contains patients' information collected through a 24-week time period. Each patient in the dataframe is represented by a single row with a unique id. There are four numerical variables (cpr, cf, h and m) that have been measured at 0, 12 and 24 weeks, so that 3 columns for each variable have been created: cpr0, cpr12, cpr24, cf0, cf12, cf24... and so on.

In order to successfully analyse this dataframe, it is much more convenient to transform it from wide to long format. What I would like to achieve is to have a new "time" variable with possible values c(0, 12, 24) and the rest of the measured variables coded without the reference to the time they were collected,  [like the sample dataframe in this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o7FA.png)

I have tried using pivot_longer() function from tidyr, but I don't seem to get the result I am expecting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We cannot read data into R from images. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourwidedata)`, if that is not too large.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make some data that resembles what you described:

```
set.seed(1001)
dataset <- data.frame(id = LETTERS[1:5],
                      cpr0 = sample(1:20, 5, replace = TRUE),
                      cpr12 = sample(1:20, 5, replace = TRUE),
                      cpr24 = sample(1:20, 5, replace = TRUE),
                      cf0 = sample(1:20, 5, replace = TRUE),
                      cf12 = sample(1:20, 5, replace = TRUE),
                      cf24 = sample(1:20, 5, replace = TRUE),
                      h0 = sample(1:20, 5, replace = TRUE),
                      h12 = sample(1:20, 5, replace = TRUE),
                      h24 = sample(1:20, 5, replace = TRUE),
                      m0 = sample(1:20, 5, replace = TRUE),
                      m12 = sample(1:20, 5, replace = TRUE),
                      m24 = sample(1:20, 5, replace = TRUE))

dataset

  id cpr0 cpr12 cpr24 cf0 cf12 cf24 h0 h12 h24 m0 m12 m24
1  A    3    11    12  12   15   11  5   8  12  5  11  14
2  B   15     6     4   3    6   14  4  20   4 15   3   2
3  C   16    14    19   1    1    2 17  20  10 13   2  13
4  D    7     4    18   8    8    4  6  18   2 11  11  20
5  E   16    12    10  18    8   20 12   2   4  6  18   9
```

We need to pivot to a longer form, separate each variable into a name and a time, and then pivot wider again to put the variable names into columns.

One way to do that, using a regex to split between letter and number:

```
library(tidyr)

dataset_pivot <- dataset %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id) %>% 
  separate(name, into = c("var", "time"), "(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "var", 
              values_from = "value")
```

Result:

```
dataset_pivot 

# A tibble: 15 x 6
   id    time    cpr    cf     h     m
   <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1 A     0         3    12     5     5
 2 A     12       11    15     8    11
 3 A     24       12    11    12    14
 4 B     0        15     3     4    15
 5 B     12        6     6    20     3
 6 B     24        4    14     4     2
 7 C     0        16     1    17    13
 8 C     12       14     1    20     2
 9 C     24       19     2    10    13
10 D     0         7     8     6    11
11 D     12        4     8    18    11
12 D     24       18     4     2    20
13 E     0        16    18    12     6
14 E     12       12     8     2    18
15 E     24       10    20     4     9
```